# Elasticsearch versioning through Tire gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have an existing Rails app that uses tire (0.4.0) to interface with an Elasticsearch (0.17.4) engine. It already has a couple of models using Tire::Persistence. I want to add a new model that takes advantage of Elasticsearch versioning, to track all changes and be able to revert to previous versions.

Right now when I retrieve any 'persisted' model instance, I check `_version` and it is always `nil`. I have not found any tire documentation that relates to versioning. Do I have to activate it somehow, or manually save records with version values? Am I even on the right track here?

I do see that certain methods return `_version` values for items, but others don't...

```
Article.first._version                          # => nil
Article.search("sample query").first._version   # => nil
Article.find("id_123")._version                 # => 8
```

Also, versioning seems to increment by 2. Perhaps tire is not fully equipped to deal with versioning. Is it saving previous versions? How can I retrieve a previous version of a record?

[EDIT] I may have misunderstood what 'versioning' actually is in Elasticsearch. Seems like it's mostly for concurrency control. Oh wellz. (I would love to hear otherwise, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, yes, as you write in the *Edit*, versions in ElasticSearch are not meant to store revisions of the document, but for concurrency control (eg. not overwriting a document with stale version).

Second, you have to declare that you want the versions returned back from search; http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/version.html

This code shows you how to do it in *Tire*.

```
require 'tire'

Tire.index('articles') do
  delete
  create
  store id: 1, title: 'One'
  store id: 2, title: 'Two'
  store id: 2, title: 'Two again'

  refresh
end

articles = Tire.search('articles') do
             query { all } 

             version true
           end.results

articles.each do |article|
  puts "Article '#{article.title}' has version #{article._version}"
end
```

For the moment, it's best to read the *Tire* integration test suite for documentation. The documentation is of course something which should and will improve.

As for your original requirement itself, similar questions have regularly popped up for CouchDB, in the past. The [Simple Document Versioning with CouchDB](http://blog.couchbase.com/simple-document-versioning-couchdb) blog post describes one nice strategy. It would be beneficial for you to research the CouchDB solutions, since the document model is similar. (Of course, CouchDB, contrary to ElasticSearch does physically store the document revisions, thus it opens a different range of strategies.)

In ElasticSearch, your basic decision regarding working with revisions would be:

**Do I want to store full revisions directly in the JSON itself?**

This could make sense for smaller documents and smaller databases. Depending on your requirements, it could make searching for historic documents very simple.

The [*Nested Type*](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type.html) in ElasticSearch would make working with these “revisions as nested documents” convenient and easy.

(You could also store just “diffs” of the documents in the JSON itself, but that would put more strain on your application logic, I bet.)

**Do I want to store revisions as separate documents?**

You may want to store revisions separately, and “link” them with their base document. The [*parent/child support*](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/parent-field.html) in ElasticSearch would make it possible to work with those relationships and queries.